# Issue with CSS Animation Hover jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I created a jQuery plugin to add simple CSS animations on Hover but unfortunately it only applies to items in the page with the .animate class applied to them. How can I make this apply to the object itself? instead of a set class or id. Please help.

```
(function($){
   $.fn.extend({

     animate: function(options) {


        var defaults = {
           animation: 'bounce'
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() 
        {
            var o = options;

            var obj = $(this);

            var animation = o.animation;

  obj.hover(function()         
  {

  switch(animation){
    case 'bounce':
          $(".animate").addClass('bounce');
          break;
    case 'shake':
          $(".animate").addClass('shake');
          break;
    case 'flash':
           $(".animate").addClass('flash');
          break; 
    case 'tada':
           $(".animate").addClass('tada');
          break;
    case 'swing':
           $(".animate").addClass('swing');
          break;
    case 'wobble':
           $(".animate").addClass('wobble');
          break;
    case 'wiggle':
           $(".animate").addClass('wiggle');
          break;
    case 'pulse':
           $(".animate").addClass('pulse');
          break;
    case 'flip':
           $(".animate").addClass('flip');
          break;
    case 'flipInX':
           $(".animate").addClass('flipInX');
          break;
    case 'flipOutX':
           $(".animate").addClass('flipOutX');
          break;
    case 'flipInY':
           $(".animate").addClass('flipInY');
          break;
    case 'flipOutY':
           $(".animate").addClass('flipOutY');
          break;
    case 'fadeIn':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeIn');
          break;
    case 'fadeInUp':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInUp');
          break;
    case 'fadeInDown':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInDown');
          break;
    case 'fadeInLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInLeft');
          break;
    case 'fadeInRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInRight');
          break;
    case 'fadeInUpBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInUpBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeInDownBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInDownBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeInLeftBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInLeftBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeInRightBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeInRightBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeOut':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOut');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutUp':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutUp');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutDown':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutDown');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutLeft');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutRight');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutUpBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutUpBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutDownBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutDownBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutLeftBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutLeftBig');
          break;
    case 'fadeOutRightBig':
           $(".animate").addClass('fadeOutRightBig');
          break;
    case 'bounceIn':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceIn');
          break;
    case 'bounceInUp':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceInUp');
          break;
    case 'bounceInDown':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceInDown');
          break;
    case 'bounceInLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceInLeft');
          break;
    case 'bounceInRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceInRight');
          break;
    case 'bounceOut':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceOut');
          break;
    case 'bounceOutUp':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceOutUp');
          break;
    case 'bounceOutDown':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceOutDown');
          break;
    case 'bounceOutLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceOutLeft');
          break;
    case 'bounceOutRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('bounceOutRight');
          break;
    case 'rotateIn':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateIn');
          break;
    case 'rotateInDownLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateInDownLeft');
          break;
    case 'rotateInDownRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateInDownRight');
          break;
    case 'rotateInUpLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateInUpLeft');
          break;
    case 'rotateInUpRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateInUpRight');
          break;
    case 'rotateOut':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateOut');
          break;
    case 'rotateOutDownLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateOutDownLeft');
          break;
    case 'rotateOutDownRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateOutDownRight');
          break;
    case 'rotateOutUpLeft':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateOutUpLeft');
          break;
    case 'rotateOutUpRight':
           $(".animate").addClass('rotateOutUpRight');
          break;
    case 'lightSpeedIn':
           $(".animate").addClass('lightSpeedIn');
          break;
    case 'lightSpeedOut':
           $(".animate").addClass('lightSpeedOut');
          break;
    case 'hinge':
           $(".animate").addClass('hinge');
          break;
    case 'rollIn':
           $(".animate").addClass('rollIn');
          break;
    case 'rollOut':
           $(".animate").addClass('rollOut');
          break;                                                                                                                              
  }
   $(".animate").addClass('animated');
},

function()
{
    $('.animate').removeClass('animated bounce bounceIn bounceInDown bounceInLeft bounceInRight bounceInUp bounceOut bounceOutDown bounceOutLeft bounceOutRight bounceOutUp fadeIn fadeInDown fadeInDownBig fadeInLeft fadeInLeftBig fadeInRight fadeInRightBig fadeInUp fadeInUpBig fadeOut fadeOutDown fadeOutDownBig fadeOutLeft fadeOutLeftBig fadeOutRight fadeInRightBig fadeOutUp fadeOutUpBig flash flip flipInX flipInY flipOutX flipOutY lightSpeedIn lightSpeedOut pulse rollIn rollOut rotateIn rotateInDownLeft rotateInDownRight rotateInUpLeft rotateInUpRight rotateOut rotateOutDownLeft rotateOutDownRight rotateOutUpLeft rotateOutUpRight shake swing tada wiggle wobble');
});              

        });

    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: have you tried `this.addClass('bounce')` etc?

Comment: i tried unfortunately it did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `this` to refer to itself, note that you don't have to do `$(this)`, since inside `this` is already referring to a `jQuery` object; from the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring):

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // there's no need to do $(this) because
    // "this" is already a jquery object
```

Comment: sorry, I'm super new to this still figuring everything out, seems like there is always a better easier way to get something done, figured i might see if i get this to work, no luck yet but thank you

Comment: @user1427307 looking at your code, I think you misunderstood how to write a plugin, try reading the docs I linked in my answer and go through it :)

Comment: yeah.. i have a bad habit of kinda just jumping into things, thank you :)

Comment: @user1427307 Try replaceing `$.fn.extend(` with `$.fn.myPlugin = function() {`

Comment: i did but i just receive a syntax error.. bleh i have a lot to figure out i think before i go jumping to this, i was super excited about making this work though

Comment: @user1427307 Look at http://jsfiddle.net/Kh3nm/3/, see if that helps you get started

Comment: @user1427307 My answer might not warrant an acceptance, but something to keep in mind: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace $(".animate") with this
That should do what you want!

Comment: i tried unfortunately it still did not work, i thought it might too